# python pandas: how to return an empty dataframe in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, functional-programming

to aggregate the content of a list of csv files , i normally do:

```
def getContent(fn):
    // do some thing with fn and generate a tempDataFrame
    return tempDataFrame


agg = pd.concat([getContent(x) for x in myListOfFiles])
```

i feel this is a very neat solution.

however, when something went wrong and i cannot find the fn or so, i need to return an empty tempDataFrame!

How can i return an empty dataframe in this case? can anyone share some experiences?

thanks!

Comment: return ``None`` as concat will ignore it

Answer (score 5):

As `pd.concat` ignores any `None` object, you can simply make your function getContent return `None`.

The only problem with this approach is if all items are `None`, it will throw an exception. If you want to prevent that, you can create an empty dataframe as the first argument with the desired columns:

```
>>> columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
>>> pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({k: [] for k in columns}), None, None])
    Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2, col3]
Index: []

[0 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: this will work, but you have to a-priori *know* the columns to specify

Comment: @Jeff yes. if you don't know what the columns are, it's probably best to leave the exception be thrown.